# how to draw line between 2 Geo points in android Google maps version 2?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I draw the line between one Geo point to another in Google maps version 2? 
 I know some accepted answers are available here. According to those answers I have to override draw() function. But I Used fragments for displaying Google maps. so I can not override that function from my activity.
Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 29):

> How can I draw the line between one Geo point to another in Google maps version 2?

`GeoPoint` is only for Maps V1. To draw lines in Maps V2, you would add a [Polyline](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html) to your `GoogleMap`:

```
  PolylineOptions line=
      new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(40.70686417491799,
                                           -74.01572942733765),
                                new LatLng(40.76866299974387,
                                           -73.98268461227417),
                                new LatLng(40.765136435316755,
                                           -73.97989511489868),
                                new LatLng(40.748963847316034,
                                           -73.96807193756104))
                           .width(5).color(Color.RED);

  map.addPolyline(line);
```

(from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Poly), described in detail in [this book](http://commonsware.com/Android))

Comment: thanks alot.I just found this answer in Google official documentation